# libpng contains a security vulnerability using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv

I am Using OpenCV in my app and published it on Play store but Google sent me this mail. How do I resolve this?

> ERROR:-
>
> This information is intended for developers of apps that utilize any version of libpng library, that contains a security vulnerability disclosed in CVE-2015-8540. Apps with vulnerabilities like this can expose users to risk of compromise and may be considered in violation of our Malicious Behavior policy.
>
> Please migrate your app(s) to libpng v1.0.66, v.1.2.56, v.1.4.19, v1.5.26 or higher as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK. Beginning Sep 17, 2016, Google Play will block publishing of any new apps or updates that use vulnerable versions of libpng. Your published app version will remain unaffected, however any updates to the app will be blocked unless they address this vulnerability.

Comment: Well, that's pretty clear, you have to check the version of libpng you are using, and if it is vulnerable, update the libpng library linked with your application, and upgrade it. What specific problem do you have with that?

Comment: As a side note, it seems that the recommended way to link with OpenCV libraries is to use the [Android OpenCV Manager](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/platforms/android/service/doc/index.html). With that approach,  you wouldn't have to worry about that kind of issue yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update to OpenCV 3.1.0 or newer - see this answer, which has more information about the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37882986/1993220

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/sofensymbole/Libpng-1.6.23

Try this link , it is created to remove vulnerability of libpng. app sucessfully uploaded by use of it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you check which file is use libpng lib using below command line in lunux pc:

```
      sudo find . -type f -exec fgrep libpng {} \; -print
```

And then update your opencv 3.2.0 using this link:

https://chmod600blog.wordpress.com/2016/02/22/how-to-add-opencv-3-1-0-to-android-studio/