# Google play security alert when using openCV2.4.X

Tags: android, opencv, android-security

Im using openCV to write c++ and java for my Android application.  there is new security alert from Google play  "libpng containing a security vulnerability".

[libpng contains a security vulnerability using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37965330/libpng-contains-a-security-vulnerability-using-opencv)

I've read that I can update openCV to 3.x to fix the issue, but there are many changes on openCV 3.0 and I don't want to update my code.

I've also tried to build openCV from trunk with the link below:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/6743

but I'm not sure I can create new libopencv_java.so file?

is there an option to use openCV 2.4.x and avoid this security alert?

Comment: How did you solve the issue?