# Google Play Store rejects apk due to vulnerable version of libpng

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, google-play, tesseract

When I try to publish my app in the Google Play Developer Console I get an error that the used version of libpng is vulnerable.

> The vulnerabilities were fixed in libpng v1.0.66, v.1.2.56, v.1.4.19,
>   v1.5.26 or higher. You can find more information about how resolve the issue in this Google Help Center article https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7011127.

However, I do not need libpng at all so I do not want to upgrade but instead remove it. My app uses OpenCV 2.4.11 and Tesseract (which again comes with leptonica). I recompiled OpenCV and Tesseract after setting the HAVE_LIBPNG flag to false using ndk-build.

When inspecting my apk file there is no libpng in the libraries folder.

Why does Google keep rejecting the app? What else can I do to get the app accepted?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Edit: 
I have read [Android: Removing OpenCV older version will resolve Libpng Vulnerability warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37875685/android-removing-opencv-older-version-will-resolve-libpng-vulnerability-warning/37882986#37882986).
I do not want to update to OpenCV 3.1 but simply remove libpng from my App. I am not using it, so a smaller apk would also be a benefit from a simple removal.

Comment: Read this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37875685/android-removing-opencv-older-version-will-resolve-libpng-vulnerability-warning/37882986#37882986

Comment: Thank you @Stanojkovic. Already read it, however, I do not want to upgrade OpenCV. I do not use libpng, so an upgrade should not be necessary.

Comment: Shouldn't you be _undefining_ `HAVE_PNG` rather than defining it to have the value 0/false? (for OpenCV that is. Tessercat might expect you to define `HAVE_LIBPNG` as 0).

Comment: Thank you @Michael for your comment. For Tesseract/Leptonica I set the HAVE_LIBPNG flag to 0. For OpenCV I did not find a HAVE_PNG or HAVE_LIBPNG flag. Is there one? Instead, I removed the liblibpng.a files for all architectures.

Comment: I think there should be one in `cvconfig.h`. Where/whether that file exists might differ between different OpenCV versions.

Comment: Unfortuantely the file does not exist in my OpenCV version. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here is what I did:

- Updated to OpenCV 2.4.13.1 which can be downloaded [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/2.4.13.1/).
- Updated Tesseract (and Leptonica which also comes with tess-two project) to the latest version.
- Before building Tesseract:

  - set HAVE_LIBPNG to 0 in tess-two/jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/config_auto.h
  - renamed Android.mk of tess-two/jni/libpng such that it is not build by include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
  - removed LIBPNG_PATH from LOCAL_C_INCLUDES in tess-two/jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/Android.mk
  - removed libpngt from LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES in tess-two/jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/Android.mk
  - removed LIBPNG_PATH from tess-two/jni/Android.mk
- Removed all System.loadLibrary("pngt") calls from Tesseract's Java files

So to summarize: my outdated version of OpenCV was one issue, but Tesseract also used a vulnerable version of libpng. Even the newer tesseract version I am using now uses this vulnerable version of libpng, so I had to manually exclude it.

If someone knows a better solution than all the points above I am still interested.