# Android libpng security vulnerability

Tags: android, libpng

I have submitted my release apk to the Google Play console, however it was rejected due to a libpng security vulnerability. I have a couple of libraries I use in my app. How do I know which of these uses libpng?

I am using Android studio.

I am not using OpenCV as a library!

These are my dependencies in my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile files('libs/sdk-v1.0.0.jar')
    compile(name: 'pen-v4.1.0_full', ext: 'aar')
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
}
```

Let me ask my question again:

How do I know which of these libraries uses libpng?

Comment: This question has already been answered...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37875685/android-removing-opencv-older-version-will-resolve-libpng-vulnerability-warning/37882986#37882986

Comment: Try googling once in a while, there are a bunch of others with the same exact problem

Comment: @Arun uhm, no. It has not been answered unfortunately. The question you have linked refers to a similar problem, but not the problem I am having.

Thx for the downvote guys ! Care to explain why ?

Comment: @TimCastelijns yes I have googled the problem. No one seems to have a proper solution in finding which library has the specific dependency.

Comment: what you do for fix this issue. i have same issue but i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @MaheshGawhane I downloaded the latest version of the Spen sdk and replaced it in my gradle build file. libpng is outdated and needs to be the latest version, so you need to find out which lib is using libpng and update that lib.

Comment: @Janpan thanx..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strings <youlibrary>.so | grep png`. If you see output full of `png_set_*`, `png_write_*`, `png_image_*` - that library uses libpng.

Comment: Thank you for actually answering my question ! I will try what you suggested and give feedback.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I used that command on all of the libraries I have in the libs folder. One of the libs is an aar file. It had a lot of png output. I think this might be the issue. Although I still experience the problem, your answer has helped me in the right direction. Thanks !

Comment: By following this method, I found that the Spen .aar library had many png methods, so I downloaded the latest version of the Spen sdk and replaced it in my gradle build file. The new version was literally a few weeks old and only changed by 1. e.g. the ol.d version was 1.0 and the new version was 1.1 . However, it solved the problem for me ! Thx for your help.

Comment: where i write this command -- strings <youlibrary>.so | grep png

Comment: In shell/terminal on Linux, macOS or other UNIX.. on Windows you can install strings command together with cygwin, for example, or use another program. The idea is to search for strings png_set_, png_write_ and png_image_ inside libraries.