# Android-Security security vulnerabilities for Libpng library

Tags: android, opencv, security, libpng

I am trying to put a new application into google play. It was not published due to security concerns in the library. In my application I use the OpenCV library. I learned that the application was not approved because of the security vulnerability in the libpng library. I have not already used the Libpng library. What is the reason of this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40116559/115145

Comment: OpenCV uses LibPNG in order to be able to read/write PNG images. If you don't need that functionality, you can disable it and rebuild the library.

Comment: Thanks for answer. How can I disable it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Removing OpenCV older version will resolve Libpng Vulnerability warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37875685/android-removing-opencv-older-version-will-resolve-libpng-vulnerability-warning)