# Libpng vulnerability issue even after updating opencv library

Tags: android, opencv, libpng, android-security

I am using following dependencies in my app :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
compile project(':zxing-2.3.0')
compile project(':ColorPickerView')
compile project(':DropboxChooserSDK')
compile project(':PullToRefreshLibrary')
compile project(':volley')
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0-alpha2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.github.ctodobom:OpenCV-3.1.0-Android:-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

I was using opencv library version 2.4.8 and google play console rejected my app saying libpng vulnerability issue. 
So i updated opencv library to 3.1.0 and still the google play console is rejecting saying the same libpng vulnerability issue.

So i am confused if any other library from above is using libpng library?

**EDIT:**

I created a sample project which has the above libraries and for testing purpose I downgraded opencv to 2.4.8 (which has libpng issue) and what can i say, it is not giving any warning about libpng, it is getting published. So where exactly is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Removing OpenCV older version will resolve Libpng Vulnerability warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37875685/android-removing-opencv-older-version-will-resolve-libpng-vulnerability-warning)

Comment: Before marking it as duplicate, read my question completely. I have upgraded opencv to latest version, but still that issue exist.

Comment: Read my comment and the other answer completely ;D 1) _Possible_ duplicate... 2) the answer mentions that 3.1 should be ok, probably is a false alarm.

Comment: @Miki i found the solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the problem.
The old opencv library(which has vulnerability issue) created ***libopencv_java.so*** file and it was still there in the ***libs*** folder even after updating the library. So somehow the new ***.so*** file was not generating.

Steps taken to solve :

- First i deleted ***libopencv_java.so*** from libs folder.
- Just for clarity, i deleted everything which was there in the ***build*** folder.
- Added opencv 2.4.13.1 gradle dependency (**compile 'com.iparse.android:opencv:2.4.13.1'**)

If you want to check the libpng version used by opencv, first find **libopencv_java.so** which will be in **libs** or **build** folder and use the following command in terminal `strings libopencv_java.so | grep "libpng"`.

After this i published in playstore and everything is fine. Hope this helps someone.