# Libpng vulnerability

Tags: android, security, opencv, libpng

My application is for live video streaming and recording (both audio and video) using wifi. uses following dependencies:

```
repositories { maven { url 'https://raw.github.com/iParse/android-library-opencv/master/releases' } }
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile project(':main')
compile files('libs/javacpp.jar')
compile files('libs/javacv.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.iparse.android:opencv:2.4.13.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/armeabi.jar')
```

Once I tried to upload to play store Google rejected my application due to Libpng vulnerability , and I found the problem with opencv lib version, so replaced the opencv jar file with its gradle dependency , and I deleted the .so files from libs/armeabi.jar folder, then Google didn't show that vulnerability issue and it got uploaded to the play store. 
 Here is the link to our application: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.steelmanpro.wifivideoscope&hl=en

The response i got from google is:

```
Hello Google Play Developer,

We rejected STEELMAN PRO – Video Scope, with package name com.steelmanpro.wifivideoscope, for violating our Malicious Behavior or User Data policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.

This app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users or allows the collection of user data without proper disclosure.

Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that were detected in your recent submission. Please upgrade your app(s) as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.

Vulnerability
APK Version(s)
Libpng library
The vulnerabilities were fixed in libpng v1.0.66, v.1.2.56, v.1.4.19, v1.5.26 or higher. You can find more information about how resolve the issue in this Google Help Center article.

3

To confirm you’ve upgraded correctly, submit the updated version of your app to the Developer Console and check back after five hours to make sure the warning is gone.

While these vulnerabilities may not affect every app that uses this software, it’s best to stay up to date on all security patches. Make sure to update any libraries in your app that have known security issues, even if you're not sure the issues are relevant to your app.

Apps must also comply with the Developer Distribution Agreement and Developer Program Policies.

If you feel we have made this determination in error, please reach out to our developer support team.

Best,

The Google Play Team
```

But now the video is'nt recording. These were the .so files used in my application:

[.so files used in the application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emLbz.png)

Comment: Please do include the Reject Reason that you got from Google Play to make it more clear .

Comment: please refer this answer[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932922/libpng-vulnerability-issue-even-after-updating-opencv-library)

Comment: this is the response I got from google:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refer this answer

- Update the opencv,javaCV,javaCpp and FFMPEG to latest version from
  the dependencies and also
- specify the architecture as "arm"
- Download
  the android arm.jar file of the same version of all libraries from
  the maven repository library
- extract the jar and copy the so files
  from the libs folder inside the all jar libraries Paste the .so files
  under src/main/jnlibs/armeabiv7a
- List item

  Also specify the ndk folder in build.gradle

Updated the gradle is as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.3.1'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.1.0-1.3', classifier:    'android-arm'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '3.2.1-1.3', classifier: 'android-arm'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/test.jar')
    compile files('libs/zxing.jar')
    compile(name:'FFmpegAndroid', ext:'aar')
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution . The FFMPEG and Opencv uses vulnerable version of libpng and We had added all Shared object files as a saperate jar file. We updated the libraries and added following dependecies

I updated the build.gradle file to

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.3.1'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.1.0-1.3', classifier:    'android-arm'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '3.2.1-1.3', classifier: 'android-arm'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/test.jar')
    compile files('libs/zxing.jar')
    compile(name:'FFmpegAndroid', ext:'aar')
    }
```