# add/update libpng latest version in my android studio project

Tags: android, libpng

Please anyone tell me the way by which i can add/update libpng latest version in my android studio project to fix the Libpng vulnerability issue. my project has only src/main/jniLibs which has /x86 & /armeabi with *.so files.
Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, based on the way you asked the question, you did not add `libpng` directly to your project.  If you had, it would be obvious that you just need to download a newer version, as specified [in the Google FAQ](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7011127).

So identify the library that you are using that itself uses `libpng` and install a later version of that library/framework.  For instance, if you were using `OpenCV`, for instance, you could check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37882986) which addresses which versions of that library has the updated `libpng`.