# Google play store Vulnerability error for libpng older version for Opencv 3.4.0

Tags: android, opencv3.0, libpng

I was using opencv 2.4.11 and than uploaded to google play store but it has rejected for vulnerability error of libpng older version. so that I updated the opencv 3.4.0. than uploaded to the play store but that error still coming. I have searched all the way but did not get any solution. got solution for libpng download but after download where is import that file I don't know. If anyone knows the answer please reply me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: from this link I have updated my opencv 2.4.11 to 3.4.0. but still that error coming from play store.

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37882986/4647628

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge here is two website where you can vulnerability test and check your issue fixed or not. Try it may be its work for you.

1) [ostorlab](https://www.ostorlab.co/)
2) [quixxi](https://quixxi.com/)

Comment: on second website this vulnerability is not find..I have checked in this.